# Find the projection of a point to a tangent plane

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

Given a surface formed by a set of 3 coordinates (x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), (x3,y3,z3) and a point p (px,py,pz). How to find the projection of p to the plane tangent to the surface?

[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ryMT.png)

In the demonstration above, Πq(p) is the point I'm looking for based on point p and surface q.

Comment: You have strange squares in your question...

Comment: What squares are you referring to?

Comment: Between "in the demonstration above" and "$\Pi q(p)$ is the point..." there are fifteen little squares...

Comment: The projection is the intersection of the perpendicular through the point with the tangent plane. Alternatively, it’s the nearest point on the tangent plane to the given point.